# Can I use IConnectivityManager, IWifiManager or ServiceManager?

Tags: android-studio

I have an app that uses these imports to access functions like setMobileDataEnabledMethod() or startTethering():

```
import android.net.IConnectivityManager;
import android.net.wifi.IWifiManager;
import android.os.ServiceManager;
```

My app compiled on Android Studio and was able to build the apk.

After Android Studio updated to 4.1 the app cannot compile. I get the error:

```
Cannot resolve symbol IConnectivityManager
Cannot resolve symbol IWifiManager
Cannot resolve symbol ServiceManager
```

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that in the Android Studio update, I also updated the SDK.
The SDK override the android.jar files that have the hidden apis. So I downloaded the hidden android.jar file again and override the sdk one.
Everything started to work as before.
I download the (hidden apis) android.jar from here: https://github.com/aeab13/android-jar-with-hidden-api